# jQuery Ajax Request 200 but status error

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, coffeescript

I'm testing out an Ajax form, and I'm getting behavior I wasn't expecting. The request returns http 200 OK, but the xhr status is 0, error. I'm testing this against [requestb.in](http://requestb.in).

Here's my function (in coffeescript):

```
$.ajax
  type: 'POST'
  url: 'http://requestb.in/1fcyas71'
  dataType: 'json'
  data: { foo: "bar" }
  error: (xhr, status, error) ->
    $('div#response').text(error).addClass('error')
    console.log status
    console.log xhr
  success: (data, status, xhr) ->
    $('div#response').text(data).removeClass('error')
    console.log status
    console.log xhr
```

My understanding is requestb.in accepts any request, so why is this returning as an error?

Comment: Is it a cross domain request ??

Comment: looks like a cross domain.. For such requests you have to use jsonp or cors !!

Comment: Yes, it is cross-domain to requestb.in and also will be when I put the real data in.

Comment: @Sushanth-- That's very helpful, but I'm a js newbie and know nothing about JSONP or CORS. Could you show me how to use those instead?

Comment: `http://requestb.in/1fcyas71` returns plain text not JSON

Comment: @Musa: Ok, so that request is returning plain text, how does that change how I should handle the response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do cross domain requests. Probably that's the issue since dont think that You are employee of http://requestb.in ?